# D3: How to assign style css to a specified id

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, parent-child

I'm trying to assign child-parent fill style from an array in D3.js to only certain polygon ids (have about 70 that need to be updated from an array). However, I've tried multiple methods, and can't figure it out.

My goal with the code sample below is to have the array countValues assign css fill styles to the id in the array called name. The css in the snippet below would be my desired output from the array.

I really appreciate your time and help with this.

```js
var countValues = [{
"name": "polygon_1",
"counts": 1
},
{
"name": "polygon_2",
"counts": 2
}];


var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")
         .attr("width", 750)
         .attr("height", 920);

var colorLow = "yellow", colorMed = "blue";

var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
     .domain([1, 2])
     .range([colorLow, colorMed]);

countValues.selectAll("name").each(function(d) {
    .style("fill", function(d){return colorScale(d.counts)})
});
```

```css
#polygon_1{
fill: yellow; 
}


#polygon_2{
fill: blue; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.4/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svgOne" width="750" height="920" style="position:absolute;">
<polygon   id="polygon_1" points="168, 20  213, 20  213, 73  168, 73 " fill="transparent"/> 
<polygon   id="polygon_2" points="214, 20  259, 20  259, 73  214, 73 " fill="transparent"/>  
<polygon   id="polygon_3" points="169, 73  212, 73  212, 133  169, 133 " fill="transparent"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`countValues` is not a D3 selection, but a simple JavaScript array. For using [selection.each](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_each), which...

> Invokes the specified function for each selected element

... you have to chain it in a D3 selection.

That being said, you have to use a `forEach`, not an `each`. Then, inside the `forEach`, you select the element by ID and apply the style:

```
countValues.forEach(function(d) {
    d3.select("#" + d.name).style("fill", colorScale(d.counts));
});
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var countValues = [{
  "name": "polygon_1",
  "counts": 1
}, {
  "name": "polygon_2",
  "counts": 2
}];


var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 750)
  .attr("height", 920);

var colorLow = "yellow",
  colorMed = "blue";

var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([1, 2])
  .range([colorLow, colorMed]);

countValues.forEach(function(d) {
  d3.select("#" + d.name).style("fill", colorScale(d.counts));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.4/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svgOne" width="750" height="920" style="position:absolute;">
<polygon   id="polygon_1" points="168, 20  213, 20  213, 73  168, 73 " fill="transparent"/> 
<polygon   id="polygon_2" points="214, 20  259, 20  259, 73  214, 73 " fill="transparent"/>  
<polygon   id="polygon_3" points="169, 73  212, 73  212, 133  169, 133 " fill="transparent"/>
</svg>
```

PS: have in mind that IDs are **unique**. If you have more than one polygon with the same ID, you're doing it wrong. Use classes instead, and change the `select` to `selectAll`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. You really helped me out and taught me a little more about D3. Thanks again!